# Can I change logging libraries in Karate?

Tags: logging, karate

I am attempting to add Karate to a project which heavily uses the latest version of log4j2. To avoid errors and behaviors associated with having multiple logging libraries as dependencies, our team has marked logback as a banned transitive dependency in the parent POM. Removing the banned dependency clause is likely not an option. Unfortunately, this means that our project will not compile after adding Karate, since Karate depends on logback.

Is there any way to switch the logging library that Karate uses? To be able to use log4j2 instead would benefit our team greatly.

If I am also considering marking logback as an excluded dependency in our child POM. How badly will this break Karate down the line??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Karate has a compile-time dependency on logback which will need some re-engineering to migrate. To be honest, this decision has served us well (especially with the Log4j [issues](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/1866)), this is the first time in 5 years that someone has requested a switch.

Do note that Karate is used as a `test` dependency in most projects. It should never leak into your production dependencies. There are also options such as maven profiles, or simply de-coupling your API testing maven project and your production (server) code, perfectly reasonable, and has its advantages (and disadvantages).

If you really need to do this change, please contact the project leads at [Karate Labs](https://karatelabs.io) for a commercial quote. You can of course attempt an open-source contribution via discussions and an eventual PR.